# Prestashop sharing product stock between two seperate prestashop websites

Tags: php, database, synchronization, prestashop

I have a two seperate websites(f.e. abc.com and 123.com) Shops have the same products, but different prices. I want that these two stores would share product stock and nothing more. So I guess it's just one column from database. Is there a good way to synchronize product stock between two seperate prestashop websites?

Comment: I guess you could do it through webservices. When stock changes in one website, update the stock in another website through webservice and vice-versa.

Comment: @TheDrot could you share more info about it?

Comment: You can use the prestashop webservice and prestashop hooks. Webservice for communicating 2 prestashop sites and use hooks for catching the stock updates/changes. And you can use StockAvailable class for getting the current stock details of products, and the same class have different functions for updating the stock

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to achieve your goal. You should use the multistore functionality in Prestashop (sharing products and stock), see doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Managing+Multiple+Shops

As I assume you aren't using it for a specific reason, you would need to go and create your own module. Your module should register to the actionUpdateQuantity hook, meaning everytime your stock changes, it should do something, namely send a message to the other shop.

Normally, you would use the Prestashop webservice for this kind of behaviour, but as the webservice has some problems with stock management (see http://forge.prestashop.com/browse/PSCSX-3170, mainly having to do with the advanced stock management). I don't know if you use the ASM functionality, but I've created an example module for syncing your stocks. It can be adapted to be compatible with ASM functionality.

In the module configuration, you'll find the Sync URL of the current shop, you can use that URL in the other shop. So you'll install the module on both shops and cross reference them. I've created a separate sync.php file which will be called to sync the stock. As said, normally you should use the webservice functionality for this (and if you dont use ASM, you can adapt it to use the webservice, if you do use ASM, you **must** adapt it to allow for stock movements and valuation).

For the code, see the repository at https://github.com/mwienk/prestashop-syncstock

Comment: Thanks for your advice,appreciate it! I decided to use multistore functionality.